# Color coding background for cells based on value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to color code the background for cells in pandas df for certain rows.
For example consider the dataframe in the link:
[Original dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hr5w.png)

What I want is white/yellow background color for cell value = 0, gradients of red for cell value < 0 depending on magnitude and gradients of green for cell value > 0.

Final dataframe should look something like below:
[Final dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6N3M.png)

This is what I have done until now:

```
import seaborn as sns    
cm = sns.diverging_palette(h_neg=10, h_pos=125, s=75, l=50, center='light', as_cmap=True)
style = [dict(props=[('border-collapse', 'separate'), ('border-spacing',  '10px 50px')]), dict(selector="th", props=[('text-align', 'center')])]
table = data_AggMetrics.style\
                            .set_properties(**{'font-family': 'Calibri', 'text-align':'center'})\
                            .set_table_styles([style])\
                            .set_table_attributes('border = "1"')\
                            .background_gradient(cmap=cm, subset = ['Abs.Delta', 'Rel.Delta'])\
                            .hide_index()\
                            .render()
```

Comment: You may want to go through this [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html)

Comment: Be aware also, for pandas styling, the output needs to be viewed as HTML. It will probably not show in a terminal window.

Comment: I went through the documentation, but I am unable to get white/yellow background for 0 value. It just considers 0 as maximum value if all other values are negative on that column and assigns it green background color. And yes I am aware that output needs to be viewed as HTML. I will be using the rendered output dataframe in an email.